# Do management operations such as database copy affect our current db performance?

Tags: azure-sql-database

Example:

I have a database named "myDb"

I execute on the master:

```
create database mydb_copy as copy of myDb
```

Will the performance of "myDb" be affected? Specifically the avg_read_io (data reads)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After executing copy database operation and database export operations, this is the data that I gathered. I used:
`select * from sys.dm_db_resource_stats` to real time query performance information.

I used a completely isolated Premium P6 (old P3) Database.

During the **create database as copy**, the **source database was not affected at all**. That means constant 0%cpu, 0%data_io, 0%log_write. At least in premium P6.

During the **database export**, **%cpu and %data_io oscilated both from 2% to 5%**. This means export operation effectively has some performance impact (very low, at least on a premium P6).

Comment: P6 is 1000 DTUs ... Do you really need that much power ? Cost wise its much expensive !

Comment: Been using Azure since 2009, with the old Web editions. Now we use Standard S1 in our product distributions. We also do Azure consulting. This client has a really bad unoptimized DB that holds an ERP with 600 users. We helped him move to azure and are trying to help him optimize his app. They use a very ugly framework that does really expensive queries, at least by default. It was client decisions to use all this horsepower. We are trying to help their techicians (we already indicated a lot of problematic queries and even reviewed some of their code base), but they are working on it.

Answer (score 1):

The performance of Azure databases will depend on what [**service tier**](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-service-tiers/?rnd=1) you are using and relies on **DTU** (database transaction unit) which represents relative power of databases based on database transaction. Azure databases are logical databases created on logical servers on different nodes within same data center, so you dont have a physical server that is dedicated for your database instance.

`sys.resource_stats` catalog view will give you a good overview of your resource usage on Azure.

From [BOL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn268335.aspx) :

> Copying a database using the CREATE DATABASE statement is an asynchronous operation. Therefore, a connection to the SQL Database server is not needed for the full duration of the copy process.
>
> When a database is copied to a new database, the new database is created with the same service tier and performance level as the source database. For example, a copy of a Premium database with P1 performance level will be created as a new Premium database with P1 performance level.

Refer to : [Azure SQL Database Performance Guidance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn369873.aspx)

Comment: You are explaining basic Sql Databse mechanics. I'm asking a very concrete question that you are not answering.

Comment: My answer tells you that `create database ..` is an async operation. So unless you are creating a copy of a very large database, you wont see minimal performance degradation. We do this every night with Azure and while you are doing this, it might increase your DTU usage which if you have configured alerts will trigger them.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Either Microsoft reference on the matter (that is not existent) or personal experience. I've done this operations hundred of times on small db's and never had problems but one of our client had this concerns on a pretty large db.

Comment: Why do you do this everynight if I may ask? Is it because it helps with index fragmentation?

Comment: @ChristianRodriguez Azure db is all about DTUs. If you have enough DTUs, then you wont even see the impact. If you are reaching DTU limits, this is where it throws you off. I can tell that when we migrated from Enterprise to this new tiers, the job that used to take 1 hr started taking 10 hours and this is when I found the real problem was undersubscribed DTU.

Answer (score 1):

It can have some performance impact depending on your SKU. DTU is a composite performance measure that includes cpu, memory, io, etc... While creating a DB as a copy doesn't add a user load on the database, it does put a load on storage. Depending on what SKU you're on, you may encounter limits on storage throughput which then affects the "regular application" performance. This is generally not noticeable unless your regular application is already causing SQL DB to use most of its DTUs.

You can find a bit of detail from the SQL DB benchmark page(https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/dn741327.aspx) which indicates storage influence on perf (as one would expect). You can also do before and after comparisons of waitstats to see if you have corresponding increase in IO related waits but as mentioned earlier, the impact may be low/negligible if you aren't already working the DB pretty hard.

Comment: This is what one could infer, that is has some, normally not noticable performance impact. Upvoting because makes sense, not marking as answer because it is a supposition,

Comment: Not supposition or conjecture. We've actually seen this and can repro in dev/test DBs. If the database is not being worked hard, the impact was not noticeable. Busy databases on Standard tier (we didn't measure Basic) had throughput % drops in the teens due to added IO and CPU load on an already busy DB. Didn't measure Premium (we have P1 through P3) but that's cos the app owners and end users didn't complain. We'll get round to measuring those eventually.

Comment: You sure it was the create database as copy operation and not export? As posted in my answer I finally tried it myself and detected 0% impact using copy operation, but some impact using export operation.